# Load HTML Page into DIV Not Working Consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is possessed, or my likely it is something so blatantly obvious, I can't see it.

The issue here is that the first link will not load the external HTML, but the second link will. Where it gets strange, is that both links work fine when I run the code locally, but when I put it out on the web, only the second link works, however, in both instances, the console.log output is the same, so I know the function is being called, the correct value is passed, and the if statement is evaluating correctly.

Additionally, I changed both links to load the same HTML file, just to make sure there isn't something odd with the loaded HTML page.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0;">

</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function loadPage(e) {      
            if (e == 1) {
                console.log(e);
                $('.contentDiv').load('pageTwo.html'); 
            }
            else {
                $('.contentDiv').load('pageTwo.html');  
            }
        };
    </script>
    <p> Start Page </p>
    <p>
        <a href="Page1" onclick="loadPage(1)" style="text-decoration:none">Page 1</a>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="Page2" onclick="loadPage(2)" style="text-`enter code here`decoration:none">Page 2</a>
    <div class="contentDiv">
        <p>Content Goes Here</p>
    </div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

pageTwo.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p> This is page Two! </p>
</body>
</html>
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: What's this "enter code here" ? is that a SO formatting problem or in the code?

Comment: Both links are the same (pageTwo.html), and you need to use ===, otherwise it is just evaluating true or false. e == 1 means is e true. and both 1 and 2 will be true.

Comment: Could you link us where you "put it out on the web?"

Comment: Looks like you're missing a closing <p> tag the button paragraph

Comment: @Madness I just tested it, `==` works fine. But I agree use `===` always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`href="page1` wont work.

It should either be `href="javascript: void(0)"` (prevent redirection) or something of similar kind which will prevent page from redirection (`event.preventDefault()` passing event object to loadPage(1, event)).

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="loadPage(2)" style="text-`enter code here`decoration:none">Page 2</a>
```

or,

```
<a href="Page1" onclick="loadPage(1, event)" style="text-decoration:none">Page 1</a>

function loadPage(e, event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    if (e == 1) {
        $('.contentDiv').load('pageTwo.html');
    } else {
        $('.contentDiv').load('pageTwo.html');
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! It was pretty obvious :-)